# Generate array from elementwise operation of vector with itself

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the "best" way to generate an array from performing an operation between each element of a vector and the whole vector?

The below example uses a loop and subtraction as the operation but in the general case, the operation could be any function.

Criteria for "best" could be: execution speed, amount of code needed, readability

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
dim = len(a)
b = np.empty([dim, dim])

def operation(x1, x2):
  return x1-x2

for i in range(dim):
  b[i,:] = operation(a, a[i])

print(b)
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html learn to use `broadcasting` and the builtin operators - minus, times, and `ufunc`.  Try to express your arbitrary operation in terms of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think numpy broadcasting will meet all of your criteria ;)

```
>>> a - a[:, None]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0]])
```